# Error con Font Awesome en Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel

Estoy haciendo una web con `Laravel`.

Pero al añadir la librería de iconos `Font-Awesome`, los `iconos` no salen y en consola me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual puede ser el error?

Los `css` y los `fonts` estan dentro de la carpeta `public`

Las llamas a los `css` la realizo así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/admin/public/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: ¿cómo estás incluyendo font awesome?

Comment: He editado mi pregunta @Shaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoría deberías llamar los recursos estáticos por medio de alguno de los helpers de laravel, para hacer esta tarea de determinar la ruta más fácil:

- [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset)

Ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: Al utilizar el ejemplo que has puesto, da error, la `url` que aparece ahora es: `C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\public\css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Qué tipo de error? 404?

Comment: No, no es 404, nose exactamente cual es: `La dirección no resulta comprensible`

Comment: Prueba con `asset()` entonces, aunque es mucho más simple esa función, en estos momentos no puedo probar.

Comment: Ahora ha funcionado correctamente, muchas gracias